# How to validate password with confirm password and then redirect?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

How can I validate password with confirm password in `login.jsp` and only if equal, then redirect to `success.jsp` which displays `Welcome #{beans.username}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement a `Validator` the usual way. Validation should surely not be done in the action method as others suggest/imply. If validation fails, then by default the action method just won't be invoked and the same page will just be redisplayed with validation errors. You can pass the password field as `<f:attribute>` of the confirm password field so that the validator can get hold of its value for test.

Here's a kickoff example of the view:

```html
<h:inputSecret id="password" binding="#{passwordComponent}" value="#{bean.password}" required="true" />
<h:message for="password" />

<h:inputSecret id="confirm" required="#{not empty password.value}">
    <f:validator validatorId="confirmPasswordValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="passwordComponent" value="#{passwordComponent}" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="confirm" />
```

and the validator:

```
@FacesValidator("confirmPasswordValidator")
public class ConfirmPasswordValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        UIInput passwordComponent = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("passwordComponent");
        String password = (String) passwordComponent.getValue();
        String confirmPassword = (String) value;

        if (confirmPassword != null && !confirmPassword.equals(password)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Confirm password is not the same as password", null));
        }
    }

}
```

The message will appear in `<h:message for="confirm">`.

Note that you only need to have the password as a property in the backing bean, not the confirm password.

```
private String password;

// Getter+setter.
```

In the action method you can just return the navigation case outcome the usual way:

```
public String login() {
    User user = userService.find(username, password); 

    if (user != null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user);
        return "success?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
            FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Unknown login, please try again.", null));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Since JSF 2.0 there's no need for verbose navigation cases in `faces-config.xml` anymore as the other answer suggest.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, why are you still sticking to the legacy JSP view technology? This has been [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) since JSF 2.0 in favor of Facelets. Please consider [migrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870) JSP to Facelets. Then you'll be able to use among others the new JSF 2.0 `<f:ajax>` awesomeness and strong Facelets templating capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define a login function in your managed bean. This function should return a string which value will apply the navigation rule described in your **faces-config.xml**.

Your *faces-config.xml* will include:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <description>
       Login
    </description>
    <from-view-id>/Login.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login_success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Success.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login_failed</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Login_failed.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Your *Beans.java* managed bean will include the login function:

```
public String login(){
    //Compare login and password against a DB, file, etc.

    if(entered_password.equals(stored_passwd){
        return "login_success";
    }else{
        return "login_failed";
    }
}
```

And finally, in your *Login.jsp* form you'll define a login button (plus the h:inputText for login and password values) similar to this:

```
<h:commandbutton value="LOGIN" action="#{Beans.login}" />
```

So, when the user presses the login button, the `login()` function will be executed and the  redirection will be determined depending on its returning value.

Comment: that is correct but i have some problem , i have three fields in jsf

Comment: 1.username 2. password 3. confirm password ..... so if two password are same only then it is showing login succes but still it is entering the succes.jsp with username

Comment: Let me see if I understood... if both `username` and `password` are correct, it redirects to succes.jsp. And also, if `password` and `confirm_password` are equal, it also displays a message in succes.jsp ?

Comment: if username is entered and password and confirm_password are not equal,still it is navigating to success.jsp

Comment: I don't understand your scenario. The main point is that you can check what you need (username, password1, and even password2) in your `login()` function and, depending on your needings, return the proper string according to your faces-config.xml declaration.

Answer (score 0):

as your password would be of type String. you can use String.equals() method to check if they are both equal.

```
   String pass1 ="#s27zaiyt0";
   String pass2 ="#s27zaiyt0";
   sysout(pass1.equals(pass2));
```

Comment: i can do that but how to redirect it to another page if pass1 and pass2 are not equal